# why netty's handler member variable does't reset when process request with new handler()

Tags: java, netty

here is my ChannelInitializer

```
ch.pipeline().addLast("httpServerCodec", new HttpServerCodec());
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
        ch.pipeline().addLast(business, new HttpSnoopServerHandler());
```

the following is HttpSnoopServerHandler code

```
public class HttpSnoopServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {

    private HttpRequest request;
    /** Buffer that stores the response content */
    private final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

     @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        // ignore process body


        buf.append("{\"key1\":[\"value1\"],\"key2\":\"value2\"}");

        // Write the response.
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);

    }
```

when i request first time , the server responses me

```
// 20200428163637
// http://localhost:8080/

{
  "key1": [
    "value1"
  ],
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

and request twice, it responses me

```
{"key1":["value1"],"key2":"value2"}{"key1":["value1"],"key2":"value2"}{"key1":["value1"],"key2":"value2"}
```

and so on .

my question is server will new Handler() to process the request. why the handler does't reset the member variable

Answer (score 0):

The `ChannelInitializer` will be called once per `Channel` (once a new connection is established). So if you keep the connection open you will need to reset state by yourself.

Comment: wow, thx a lot, this explanation is really helpful for netty learner .